# Почему prompt не выводит сообщение?

Tags: javascript, html, функции

```
function cube(cb) {
    var n = (prompt('Введите куб');
    var n=cb*cb*cb;
    document.write('Куб числа '+cb+ '=' + n);
}
```

Comment: Скобка перед prompt лишняя

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Друг мой вы просто банально забыли закрыть лишнию скобку на второй строке кода.
Попробуйте вот так:

```
n = prompt('Введите куб');

function cube(cb) {
    var n = cb**3;
    document.write('Куб числа ' + cb + ' = ' + n);
}

cube(n);
```

Comment: Спасибо, помог)

Answer (score 1):

Лучше всего чтобы каждая функция отвечала только за что-то одно, поэтому давайте отделим мух от котлет:

```
// Объявление функции вычисления 3-й степени числа
function cube(cb) {
    return cb*cb*cb; // лучше cb**3
}

// Запрос значения
let n = +prompt('Введите значение:', 0);

// Вычисление значения куба числа
let cb = cube(n);

// Вывод результата
document.write('Куб числа '+n+ ' = ' + cb);
```

Comment: Не ответ на вопрос «Почему»

Comment: @andreymal почему, я написал в комментарии, а ответ дал в догонку как совет, видя что вопрос скоро закроют, ибо в нем банальная опечатка